# Proper use of git checkout --no-overlay

Tags: git

When I use `git checkout --no-overlay` I get the following error:

```
$ git checkout --no-overlay master 
fatal: '--[no]-overlay' cannot be used with switching branches
```

I thought the point of the `--no-overlay` flag was to make my working directory match the commit (or HEAD of master in this example) byte-for-byte, i.e. remove any files in the working directory that are not present master. Am I misunderstanding the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt---no-overlay)?

> --no-overlay
>
> In the default overlay mode, git checkout never removes files from the index or the working tree. When specifying --no-overlay, files that appear in the index and working tree, but not in <tree-ish> are removed, to make them match <tree-ish> exactly.

I'm trying to remove the mess from an alternative directory structure from older commits and make my current working directory match master. As an alternative, I could do:

```
$ rm -rf myRepoRootPath
$ git checkout master
```

but this seems non-ideal as it will

1. Remove and move a bunch of files that actually overlap (slow for larger repos)
2. Kind of scary to use rm -rf on a regular basis (one typo can ruin your day/week)

Comment: The overlay/no-overlay stuff is meant more for internal use and things like sparse-checkout. They used to be internal-only; during work on `git restore`, people realized that there were certain weird corner cases where you might want `git checkout` of the *current* commit to be able to do either variant. You can't mix it with branch-switching, as you've seen. Normally you'd use `git reset` or `git restore` to fix things up, then `git checkout` to switch.

Comment: Thanks @torek. I'm still confused on the documentation regarding overlay though. If the default behavior "never removes files from the index or the working tree" then after  `git checkout someOldCommit` followed by `git checkout master` I would expect files in `someOldCommit` to still exist in the working directory.  

When starting this post they were remaining, but after `rm -rf myRepoRootPath` followed by `git checkout master` and a `git reset --hard HEAD` I can no longer observe this behavior when checking out between them. Any idea what would cause a repo to react differently like this?

Comment: It's a bit messy... to understand all of this properly, you need to know how Git handles `git read-tree`, which is the real root of all of these various operations. There are a lot of variants. In each case there are some files in Git's index, some files in your working tree, and an internal Git tree object (usually the tree associated with a commit). When using `git checkout <other>`, if the current index or working tree has a file that doesn't match the *current* commit, it's normally retained, but not with `--force` (which maybe also sets no-overlay mode, I haven't checked).

Comment: The `git read-tree` documentation describes this retaining mode under the section "two tree merge", and lists 21 (!) special cases.

Comment: Oof! Thats a fair bit to take in and as I can't seem to get back to the state that brought me here, hard to further investigate what caused my specific issue. I'm satisfied knowing where to find this two tree merge doc and the brute force recovery methods (hard resets, or `rm -rf` calls). If you want to put these in an answer, I'm happy to mark it (if points mean anything to a user with 338k already!)

Comment: I'll leave it open in case someone (VonC or bk2204 perhaps) wants to put in a better answer about the overlay stuff: it's pretty new and I haven't *used* it myself for anything yet, so it's not quite solid in my own mind either.

Comment: @topher217 Why did you use 'rm' before checkout? I think 'checkout' and 'reset --hard' should drop all garbage in your working tree.

Comment: @topher217 Ok. 'reset --hard' is not enough. However 'git clean -dfx' might be safer than 'rm -rf'. How important cache reset for you?

Comment: @benaja I had been using `git clean -df` but I don't believe I ever tried the `-x` option. I'll give it a go if I ever get into a similar state again. I honestly don't remember what made the cache reset so important when writing this OP, but do vaguely recall something along the lines of my compiler not compiling because some code in the cache was broken so I couldn't compile the actual code of interest without adding temporary ignore code to the compilation process. Something along those lines.